# Sibling route is not being replaced but appended to the previous url react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, frontend, react-router-dom

I've been implementing a nested route feature in react using `react-router` v6.
When I go to the next sibling route it's just adding it to the previous sibling for example I want that when I go to "sibling 1" it should show url/home/sibling1 and then if I want to go to "sibling 2" it should route to url/home/sibling2 which is not the case, it's just appending sibling 2 to 1 like this "url/home/sibling1/sibling2".

Here is my route file:-

```
function App() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter> 
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/home' element={<Home />} >
          <Route path='sibling1' element={<Sibling1 />} />
          <Route path='sibling2' element={<Sibling2 />} />
          <Route path='sibling3' element={<Sibling3 />} />
        </Route>
        <Route path="*" element={<Page404 />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}
```

and here is how I am navigating from sibling 1 to sibling 2:-

```
<div className='btn'>
  <Link to="sibling2">
    <button>
      sibling2
    </button>
  </Link>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To navigate to a sibling route ***from*** one of the other sibling components you will want to navigate relative to the parent `Routes` component. Prepend the target path with `".."`. `".."` removes one path segment, i.e. from `"/home/sibling1"` to `"/home"`, then navigates relatively to result path `"/home/sibling2"`.

Example:

```
<Link to="../sibling2">
  <button>
    sibling2
  </button>
</Link>
```

[image: Edit sibling-route-is-not-being-replaced-but-appended-to-the-previous-url-react-route]

Comment: I actually did use this for some reason I thought this was a workaround, because I saw some tutorials and videos and they actually didn't prepend it with ".." they just used the name of the sibling and for some reason their code worked.
But Thank you So Much anyway! This does work.

Comment: @AnugrahBhatt They were likely rendering the links/buttons from the parent component, i.e. `Home` in your code's case. From `Home` any links to `"sibling1"` or `"sibling2"` will still link relative to the current path, i.e. `"/home"` where `Home` is rendered. I've updated the sandbox to show both.